# Full height calendar with Bootstrap 4 table

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, html-table

I'm trying to create a calendar using a Bootstrap 4 bordered table that takes up 100%vh, has each row the same width but a different height for the header(which contains the days of the week).
https://codepen.io/GeoHurdle/pen/ZEpyzLZ

```html
<div class="table-responsive">
  <table class="table table-bordered">
    <thead>
      <tr class="d-flex">
        <th scope="col" class="col-3">Sun</th>
        <th scope="col" class="col-3">Mon</th>
        <th scope="col" class="col-3">Tue</th>
        <th scope="col" class="col-3">Wed</th>
        <th scope="col" class="col-3">Thu</th>
        <th scope="col" class="col-3">Fri</th>
        <th scope="col" class="col-3">Sat</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr class="d-flex">
        <td class="col-3" scope="row">1</td>
        <td class="col-3">2</td>
        <td class="col-3">3</td>
        <td class="col-3">4</td>
        <td class="col-3">5</td>
        <td class="col-3">6</td>
        <td class="col-3">7</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="d-flex">
        <td class="col-3" scope="row">8</td>
        <td class="col-3">9</td>
        <td class="col-3">10</td>
        <td class="col-3">11</td>
        <td class="col-3">12</td>
        <td class="col-3">13</td>
        <td class="col-3">14</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

```css
html,
body {
  overflow-y: hidden;
}

.table [class^='col-'] {
  flex-shrink: 1;
}

tr {
  height: calc(100vh / 3);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the table if you use grid layout, you can do it more easily

```css
html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        }
        .wrapper {
        border: 1px solid blue;
        height: 100%;
        padding: 10px;
        }

        .grid {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: auto auto auto auto auto auto auto;
        grid-template-rows: 50px auto auto;
        row-gap: 7px;
        }

        .grid>div {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        border: 1px solid;
        background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
        font-size: 30px;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        }
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
        <div class="grid">
            <div>Sun</div>
            <div>Mon</div>
            <div>Tue</div>
            <div>Wed</div>
            <div>Thu</div>
            <div>Fri</div>
            <div>Sat</div>
            <div>1</div>
            <div>2</div>
            <div>3</div>
            <div>4</div>
            <div>5</div>
            <div>6</div>
            <div>7</div>
            <div>8</div>
            <div>9</div>
            <div>10</div>
            <div>11</div>
            <div>12</div>
            <div>13</div>
            <div>14</div>
            
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Your code doesn't make the table fill the height of the view-port and I see your using Bootstrap 5 (which is still in beta) not Bootstrap 4.

Comment: In this case, Bootstrap 5 or Bootstrap 4 does not matter really. Because I did not touch your HTML code. I have just changed your custom CSS. It seems that you have changed your codepen codes. Instead of "thead tr" you just declare a class (theHeader) there. Is your problem solved or not?

Comment: Sorry about the change to the Codepen (multiple versions and changes). No, it's still not filling the height of the view-port.

Comment: Add a photo in your post, so that we can understand better.

Comment: I can't embed a picture yet, I don't have enough reputation points, but if you look at the codepen the last row of the calendar should go all the way to the bottom of the page. (all rows except the one that contains the days of the week should be the same height)

Comment: I don't want to use div's, as I stated in the original question, I want to use a Bootstrap 4 bordered table.

Comment: OK, I was partially successful in making the table, but I the positioning of my "forward" and "back" buttons isn't right and I'm not sure how to fix them. https://jsfiddle.net/9e5c6xk8/

Comment: check this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65484753/positioning-buttons-next-to-image/65485414#65485414

Answer (score 0):

There is already a discussion on [why not use tables for layout in HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/q/83073/2410655). If you have to use Bootstrap table to structure the calendar, then you can ignore my answer, or just delete it.

If you want to see how it can be done in flexbox, then keep on reading.

#### Structure

Just by looking at your source code, I can tell there are 3 major sections in your calendar. So I would first structure them like following:

```html
<section class="calendar">
    <section class="month-selection">
        <a href="#">
            <i class="fas fa-arrow-left"></i>
        </a>
        <div class="month">DECEMBER</div>
        <a href="#">
            <i class="fas fa-arrow-right"></i>
        </a>
    </section>
    <section class="days-of-week">
        <div class="day-of-week">Sunday</div>
        ...
    </section>
    <section class="days">
        <div class="day">1</div>
        ...
    </section>
</section>
```

One of your requirements is that you want the calendar to take up 100% view height.

It's not hard to do via CSS/SCSS:

```css
.calendar {
    height: 100vh;
}
```

I guess the tricky part is how to make the days in `days` section to automatically fill up the gaps while not setting fixed heights on `month-selection` and `days-of-week` section.

The trick I had is that I have the calendar display as flexbox, and I set its flow to column, and I only set the height of `days` section to 100%. Yes, `days` section will try to set self height to 100% of HTML body, but since it's a child of a flexbox, it will shrink (by default) to take up only available space! (if flowing as column is hard to imagine, think about the row flow)

```css
.calendar {
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column nowrap;

    .days {
        height: 100%;
    }
}
```

As long as `days` section is taking up the rest of available space, later on when we style each individual day, we would be able to automatically adjust their heights!

#### Height of each day

Another question would be how to automatically adjust the height of each day box in `days` section so that they will take up the rest of spaces.

Well believe or not, it's super easy with flexbox!

The only thing you need to do, beside setting `days` section as flexbox, is to set `align-items` to `stretch` (which is even the default)!

```css
.days {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    align-items: stretch;
    height: 100%;

    ...
}
```

#### Screenshot

[image]

**demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/davidliang2008/uc4stzp5/107/